# Should we have a 'closed' tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

I would not mind tagging questions as [closed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed), so that I can put [closed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closed) in my 'not interesting list' and ignore them. It's kind of a hack to save those micro-seconds I spend on closed questions. What do you think?

Comment: The MSO question on this subject (with a Jeff answer) - [Can Closed questions be hidden/filtered?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83213/can-closed-questions-be-hidden-filtered) - its also not difficult to do via search: [is:question closed:no \[java\]](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ano+%5Bjava%5D) and variations on that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What if a closed question already has 5 tags?

Tags are for categorizing questions, not to filter them by status. If we go forward with this, soon we'll want a [on-hold](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-hold), a [protected](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protected) and then a [locked](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/locked), [migrated](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrated) and why not a [deleted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleted)...

These things belong in the question's title, like `blablabla [on hold]`.

---

Since the idea is to have these questions show as "not interesting", perhaps there could be a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) made, to make questions with one of these statuses show up faded in the questions list, like questions tagged with "ignored tags"?

[image]

Comment: I'd agree, if I could filter on titles.

Comment: @tomdemuyt how about simply having them show up as "not interesting", as if they were tagged with one of your "ignored tags"? (see edit)

Comment: The difference is that there's no tag involved, rather just the question list made a little bit "smarter".

Comment: That could work as well, and we would avoid the extra tagging.

Comment: I'd actually upvote such a feature request. I did downvote this one though, because of the idea of introducing these tags. I think it should be posted on MSO though (wouldn't it be SE-wide?).

Comment: Not to go meta on meta, but I think down-voting means that the style of the question is bad, not that you disagree with the content ;)